# how do I change the code in a sheet by applying a module

Tags: excel, vba

I made a module that I want to be a plugin. My issue is I want it to rerun every time I open the sheet and only the sheet I activated it on.

I found a solution on how to do it by using the

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     Call Func
End sub
```

inside the sheet, I applied the macro to. How can I make it apply this code snipped to the currently active sheet when automatically when I activate the macro.

Basically, when I use my plugin while I am on sheet x I want it to apply

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     Call Func
End sub
```

this function to that specific sheet and that specific sheet only

Just to clarify better.

I want to sit on the sheet that has NO VBA code associated,

activate my add-in

and have a predefined code-block run in the context of the activated sheet.

Comment: Event `Worksheet_Activate` executes when you activate that specific sheet, so it becomes the ActiveSheet, and your `Func` will execute on ActiveSheet, unless in the code of `Func` there is something that changes the active sheet.

Comment: When you assign `worksheet` in vba-code, use `activesheet`

Comment: You can click on your sheet (right button), choose the View Code option and introduce the code you want to execute when you choose this WorkSheet. Is it ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following codes to your Add-In, it is important to add them to the right module (as indicated by the comments in the code).

```
' ThisWorkbook

Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    InitializeMyEventHandler ThisWorkbook.Application
End Sub


' modMyEventHandler

Option Explicit

Public g_mehHandler As clsMyEventHandler

Public Sub InitializeMyEventHandler(eapApplication As Application)
    Set g_mehHandler = New clsMyEventHandler
    Set g_mehHandler.eapApplication = eapApplication
End Sub


' clsMyEventHandler

Option Explicit

Public WithEvents eapApplication As Application

Private Sub eapApplication_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If TypeName(Sh) = "Worksheet" Then
        Dim ewsSheet As Worksheet: Set ewsSheet = Sh
        Debug.Print "Worksheet activated. Workbook: " & ewsSheet.Parent.Name & ", Worksheet: " & ewsSheet.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

The first part in the Add-In's ThisWorkbook module makes sure that our event handler class will be initialized each time the Add-In is loaded (when a new Excel Application is opened).

The second part is a normal public module, which is capable of holding global public objects, in our case an object of class clsMyEventHandler. At initialization g_mehHandler will be set to a new instance of clsMyEventHandler, and its member, eapApplication will be assigned to the Application object received from the Add-In's Workbook_Open function.

The third part must be added as a class module. It has a variable that is declared with WithEvents, this means that any time an event (e.g. activation of a new sheet) happens, the appropriate functions of this class module will be called. If a SheetActivate event is fired in eapApplication, then eapApplication_SheetActivate function of this class will be called. The function is selected based on its name (object name + underscore + event name). After you declared eapApplication (`Public WithEvents eapApplication As Application`), you will be able to select eapApplication from the ComboBox above the VBA code, which usually contains the word (General). If you selected eapApplication there, you will be able to select events to which you want to react from the ComboBox next to it.